# Como ejecuto un programa de visual studio (c#) en una computadora que no tenga nada de visual studio instalado?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows, instalacion, ejecutar

Hace unos meses estoy aprendiendo a usar c# con visual studio y ahora mismo logré un trabajo bastante integrador (un juego de cartas) y quería mandárselo a un amigo para que lo probara en su computadora y me diera sus impresiones pero no sé cómo hacer que lo ejecute si no tiene instalado visual studio ni nada de eso.

Estuve investigando y al menos en windows si le pones la ruta de donde tienes la carpeta Microsoft.Net/Framework/csc.exe en una configuración ahí que es un Path en una variable de entorno puedes ejecutar un archivo .cs desde la terminal, lo hice y me funcionó pero cuando intenté ejecutar mi programa solo me trabajaba con la clase que ejecutaba, no llamaba a las otras clases. Me sale el error **Program.cs(7,17): error CS0246: No se puede encontrar el tipo o el nombre de espacio de nombres 'Game' (¿falta una directiva using o una referencia de ensamblado?)**

En mi computadora el programa se ejecuta normalmente usando dotnet, no se si tenga que hacer algo distinto o que.

Comment: Click derecho en el proyecto y buscas publicar. Ahi tienes varias configuraciones y formas de publicación

Comment: Otra opción de publicar: Cada vez que ejecutas el proyecto, se debe de crear una carpeta debug y release con los archivos necesarios para su ejecución, entonces una de esas carpetas la puedes enviar a otra pc sin necesidad de visual studio.